# Переключатель на jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Немного представления.
Блок поделен на 2 части левая и правая.

Слева элементы списка, справа картинки свернутые в один блок с абсолютным позиционированием, представляют из себя некий сэндвич )

Логика следующая: 
По нажатию на один из элементов списка

```
<a id="lin_lay_1" onclick="dev_clicker1();">Первый элемент</a>
```

Первый слой сэндвича [.dev_layer1] поднимается на 80px.

```
click = 1;
function dev_clicker1(){
    if(click){
        $(".dev_layer1").animate({
            top: "-80px",
        }, 500);
        $(".dev_layer1").css({zIndex: "5"}, 500);
        click = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $(".dev_layer1").animate({top: "0"}, 500);
        click = 1;
    }
}
```

На текущий момент при нажатии на второй элемент списка [#lin_lay_1], 
поднимается второй слой сэндвича [.dev_layer1], однако первый не опускается.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы первый слой опускался при нажатии на второй элемент списка или любой другой всего 6 элементов в списке также как и 6 слоев в сэндвиче.

з.ы. junior. кусок js в данном случае исполняет работает только одного элемента, тоесть его нужно скопировать 6 раз и поменять классы с id, как можно этого избежать в данном примере ?

Comment: Напишите первым действие при выполнение спрятать все из второго блока. Если будет html код я вам покажу, или могу сгенерировать сам если не поняли что я имею в виду.

Comment: В bootstrap это уже реализовано я бы использовал их библиотеку чтобы не писать велосипед.